# What does the check mark `Lock document after signing` do in Acrobat Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader, pdf-reader, digital-signature

I need to sign PDF documents with the Acrobat Reader DC (V19, Win10).

What consequences does the check mark `Lock document after signing` specifically have? This is what I checked/got so far (partly from the existing answers/comments), when you open it in various PDF readers (e.g. Adobe Reader, Foxit, etc.) which support digital signatures:

- It disables editing tools (e.g. annotation tool)
- It disables form fields
- It blocks additional signatures (if there should be multiple signatures on the document the first person not enable the lock)

This is, what I noticed so far and is included in the [FAQ file](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/edit-signed-PDF.html) which, unfortunately, the FAQs are rather unsubstantial.

Is it still possible to remove the signature if the signature if the document needs to be edited after it got signed (in case the unsigned file got lost)? [image: PDF signature dialogue]

Comment: From experience in Adobe Reader it (at least) locks all editable fields once the document is signed. I do not know about the annotation and comment tools. Only the person who applied the signature can remove it once applied.

Comment: @Mokubai thanks, that is an interesting additional fact. So in case of a PDF form you are not allowed to enter anything in those fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe [Edit a signed PDF | FAQ](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/edit-signed-PDF.html)
says this:

> **What if a PDF is locked after signing?**
>
> Occasionally, you or the signer may choose to lock the document after
> signing. In this case, the document becomes read-only and no further
> changes are allowed; even a signature can’t be added in the document.
> The *Lock document after signing* option is useful if you’re the last
> signer or the only one signer.

This option allows locking the document from further editing or signing
after your signature is placed.
Select this only if you are the last person to digitally sign this document,
because it locks the document and all of the fields in it,
making it totally read-only.

For removal of the signature, the same FAQ says this:

> **Can I edit a PDF that I signed?**
>
> If you’re the only one signer, you can remove the signature and then
> work on the document or edit the source document.
>
> To remove your signature, right-click the signature and then choose
> Clear Signature.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get any information on the 2nd part of the question (removal of the signature)? Otherwise I will split the question into two, so at least I can accept your answer for the first part.

Comment: It's in the same FAQ - I added this to the answer.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed that one (or it wasn't there the last time I looked)... thanks!

Comment: Ok, after trying it (again) I remember what the problem was using clear signature (I tried this when I wrote the question): This does not remove the "complete" signature. The signature field does not be removed, it just shows an empty signature field. Any ideas how I can remove the empty signature field as well?

Comment: I don't know of a way for doing that.